# Load Related Module with Many to many type using sugar crm of node js

Tags: node.js, sugarcrm

I am new with sugar crm api and i use it with node js .My question is how can i load all related Module of a specefic one that have Many to Many.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to loading relationship details of a record, you can achieve that in SugarCRM with something like this:

```
//Load Account
$bean = BeanFactory::getBean('Accounts', $id);

//If relationship is loaded
if ($bean->load_relationship('contacts'))
{
    //Fetch related beans
    $relatedBeans = $bean->contacts->getBeans();
}
```

API documentation: https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.6/API/Classes/SugarBean/Fetching_Relationships/